# R equivalent of Stata *

Tags: r, stata

In Stata, if I have these variables: `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`, `var5`, and `var6`, I can select all of them with the command `var*`. Does R have a similar functionality?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `var*` is not a command, but a _varlist_ (a list of variable names) that uses a special character or wildcard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `grep` to do this kind of regexp matching among the column names:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3)
df = data.frame(var1=x, var2=x, var3=x, other=x)
df[, grep("var*", colnames(df))]
```

Output:

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3
```

So, basically just making use of the usual `df[rows_to_keep, columns_to_keep]`
indexing syntax, and feeding in the results of `grep` as the `columns_to_keep`.

Comment: @bill999 To be safe (and to match the Stata query), you'd want to use `"^var*"` to make sure that the varname starts with `"var"`. Try `grep("var*",c("revarnish"))`

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah, you're right. The `*` isn't needed. Ah, the comment disappeared, but: `"^var"` is sufficient; there's no need to finish with `*`.

Answer (score 12):

The `select` function from the "dplyr" package offers several flexible ways to select variables. For instance, using @Marius's sample data, try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(starts_with("var"))        # At the start
df %>% select(num_range("var", 1:3))     # specifying range
df %>% select(num_range("var", c(1, 3))) # gaps are allowed
```