# R equivalent of Stata * in regression

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, tidyverse, stata

I am looking for an equivalent in R of Stata's * function that I can use when running regressions.

For example, if I have a dataframe like the following:

```
outcome  var1  var2  var3  new
  3        2     3     4    3
  2        3     2     4    2
  4        3     2     1    4
```

I would like to be able to select all variable names that begin with "var" without typing each one out separately in order to run the following regression more efficiently:

```
lm(outcome ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + new, data = df)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845666/r-equivalent-of-stata) explains how I can select the necessary columns. How can I cleanly incorporate these into a regression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One technique is to subset the data to the required columns, and then to use the `.` operator for the [formula](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula) object to represent the independent variables in `lm()`.  The `.` operator is interpreted as "all columns not otherwise in the formula".

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),nrow = 100)*100)
colnames(data) <- c("outcome", "x1","x2","x3","x4", "x5","x6", "x7", "var8", "var9")

# select outcome plus vars beginning with var
desiredCols <- grepl("var",colnames(data)) | grepl("outcome",colnames(data))

# use desiredCols to subset data frame argument in lm()
summary(lm(outcome ~ .,data = data[desiredCols]))
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(lm(outcome ~ .,data = data[desiredCols]))

Call:
lm(formula = outcome ~ ., data = data[desiredCols])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-57.902 -25.359   2.296  26.213  52.871 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 58.712722   7.334937   8.005 2.62e-12 ***
var8         0.008617   0.101298   0.085    0.932    
var9        -0.154073   0.103438  -1.490    0.140    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 29.86 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02249,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.002331 
F-statistic: 1.116 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 0.3319

>
```